# Laravel 4 - How orderBy date with Query Builder

Tags: sql, datetime, laravel-4, query-builder

I have a list of date (expiry_at)

```
02-18-2014
02-13-2014
02-20-2014
02-15-2014
```

And i would like to use OrderBy on theses dates

Results :

```
02-13-2014
02-15-2014
02-18-2014
02-20-2014
```

I have tried :

```
DB::table('users')
        ->select('users.address', 'products.created_at', 'users.lat', 'users.lng',
            'users.name', 'users.email','products.photo', 'products.price', 'products.quantity',
            'users.tel', 'products.title', 'products.user_id', 'products.id',
            'products.description', 'products.expiry_at', 'users.email', 'users.photo as user_photo')
        ->join('products', 'users.id', '=', 'products.user_id')
        ->whereNull('shared_at')
        ->whereNull('deleted_at')
        ->orderBy('products.expiry_at', 'ASC')
        ->paginate(10);
```

but It order :

```
02-15-2014
02-13-2014
02-18-2014
02-20-2014
```

Why ?
Thanks

Comment: Hi. this is my application in production : http://screencloud.net/v/fiTL -> '02-13-2014' before '02-11-2°14'

Answer (score -1):

Hey you can use `DB::Raw("DATE('product.expiry_at as expiry_at')","ASC")`

```
DB::table('users')
    ->select('users.address', 'products.created_at', 'users.lat', 'users.lng',
        'users.name', 'users.email','products.photo', 'products.price', 'products.quantity',
        'users.tel', 'products.title', 'products.user_id', 'products.id',
        'products.description', 'products.expiry_at', 'users.email', 'users.photo as user_photo')
    ->join('products', 'users.id', '=', 'products.user_id')
    ->whereNull('shared_at')
    ->whereNull('deleted_at')
    ->orderBy("DATE('product.expiry_at as expiry_at')", 'ASC')
    ->paginate(10);
```

Hope it works!

Comment: Hi Patrik, thanks for help. It doesn't works for me.